# What to return from fields.function in openerp7

Tags: field, odoo

I have a field function:

```py
 def _get_something(self, cr, uid, ids, name=None, arg=None, context={}):

        record = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)[0]
        # code...
        res = {}

        for i in obj.browse(cr, uid, some_ids, context=context):
            res[record.id] = i.id

        return res
```

In my colummns:

```
'sample_ids': fields.function(_get_something, type='one2many', string='Test', method=True, relation='the other object', store=False)
```

To explain this better:
The problem is that i don't know what to return from the function above so i can show the records of the 'some_ids' in this tree view.
It returns an error `record[f] = res2[record['id']]`.
Any help?(if cannot understand,please tell me to explain better)

Comment: tip: always provide the version of Odoo / OpenERP when asking a question about that framework.

Comment: Yes you're right!!I edit it!Thank you.Problem solved.....!:D

Comment: if problem solved, please "accept" the answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res` is a dictionary mapping the `id` of the record for which the field is being computed to a list which contains the `id`s of the related records:

```py
def _get_something(self, cr, uid, ids, name=None, arg=None, context={}):
    res = {}
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        # code...
        res[record.id] = []
        for i in obj.browse(cr, uid, some_ids, context=context):
            res[record.id].append(i.id)
    return res
```